# How to create a JSON variable from a SOAP Response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services, soap

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 and need to return a SOAP (XML) Response to a JSON variable within javascript on the page.  Than I would like to be able to call the variable and it's properties as you would with any JSON variable.  The Soap Web Service (.asmx) file is not on the server where I need to build the client-side (receiving the request and putting it into a JSON variable).  Also, to make this more complicated, the XML Request that gets send to the Web Service needs to send a UserName and Password to be able to return the items.

The URL for the Web Service is here:  http://ws.idssasp.com/members.asmx?wsdl

Figured I would create a Visual Studio Web Application Project (C#), which I was able to do and connect to the Web Service just fine, however, This needs to be on a page that javascript uses to output the items that come from the methods of the web service.  So, a .aspx file would not work in this case, since it would need to output only the result of the web service response in a JSON variable within a  tag (probably in the head of the page, but doesn't matter to me where).  Or it could dynamically create a .JS file (which would probably be better, since it would be cached and wouldn't need to call the web service multiple times if the js file exists on my server).  However, I'm not sure on what to build in Visual Studio to accomplish this?  And I'm not sure on how it would be used to output it onto the page.  I suppose the JSON variable could also be stored within a `Members.json` file on the server and could just call that to load up the json needed.

How to return a JSON array from SOAP, XML, Response... after sending a request to another server with UserName and Password in the header of the SOAP Request.  There is a page here that explains the XML needed for the Request and what the response will look like:  http://ws.idssasp.com/members.asmx?op=GetMemberList&pn=0

On this same page, they show you how to do it via PHP, but PHP is not available, and only have ASP.NET 4.0 available to me.  Here is their PHP way of doing it:

```
$clientWS = new SoapClient('http://ws.idssasp.com/Members.asmx?wsdl');
$namespaceWS = 'http://ws.idssasp.com/Members.asmx';

$dmsClientU = '';
$dmsClientP = '';

$headerBodyWS = array('UserName' => $dmsClientU, 'Password' => $dmsClientP);
$headerWS = new SOAPHeader($namespaceWS, 'AuthorizeHeader', $headerBodyWS, false);
$clientWS->__setSoapHeaders(array($headerWS));

$results = $clientWS->GetMemberList();

print_r( $results );
```

How would I be able to do the same thing here is ASP.NET 4.0, but instead of returning the XML result, return a JSON variable that gets used within a script tag on the page?

Or maybe I am overthinking this and there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to the web service and retrieving objects without issues, you should be able to construct JSON objects out of the properties of the SOAP responses.

I suggest creating a web service in ASP.NET, converting the SOAP response to JSON in the C# server code, then using AJAX in the JavaScript of your page to retrieve the JSON from your web service. Basically, you would be creating your own specialized conversion web service for your project that sits in the middle.

Keep the credentials you need server-side for your .asmx conversion service. Whatever you do, do not put credentials in the client-side JavaScript for a web service call, even if it lets you avoid writing server-side code.

For some reference on ASP.NET web services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot!  Thinking that the credentials will go into the other Web Service.  But it's confusing to think of a WebService inside of another Web service... will need to think about what I need to put in the `web.config` file in the root of the site a bit...

Comment: Also, how do you convert SOAP to JSON?  I haven't seen any good examples of this, but maybe they do exist...

Comment: Don't think of the new web service as *inside* of another web service - it's just consuming XML from the external service you're referencing and converting it to JSON for your page's JavaScript to consume instead. Since your project is referencing a WSDL, the SOAP response should return as an ordinary C# object. In your service's web method, the returned C# object then just needs to be serialized into JSON, which can be done manually by constructing a JSON string, but preferably with a tool like JSON.NET: http://james.newtonking.com/json